# When inserting data to database using JavaScript Error creates in console 'Maximum call stack size exceeded'

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I searched a lot to fix my JavaScript Error I'm facing from the last few days. I see lots of questions answered on **StackOverFlow**, but unfortunately, no one is matching to my error.

What I want is to send a simple record to the **database** using **JavaScript** and **PHP**.

but I'm getting "**jquery.js:8638 Uncaught RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded**" error in **Console**.
Thanks for your response.

My simple **HTML** code

```html
        
<form autocomplete="off">
    <div class="form-group col-sm">
        <label for="fname">First Name</label>
        <input type="text" name="fname" id="fname" class="form-control">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group col-sm">
        <label for="lname">Last Name</label>
        <input type="text" name="lname" id="lname" class="form-control">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group col-sm">
        <button class="btn btn-primary" type="submit" id="submitBtn">Submit</button>
    </div>
</form>
```

And **javaScript** code

```html
$(document).ready(function(){
$("#submitBtn").on("click",function(e){
e.preventDefault();
var fname = $("#fname").val();
var lanme = $("#lname").val();

$.ajax({
    url : "insertData.php",
    type : "POST",
    data : {fname:fname, lname:lname},
    success : function(data){
        if(data == 1){
            tableData();
        }else{
         alert("Can't save record");   
        }

    }
});
})
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `submit` function on your `form` instead of using a `click` function on `type="submit"` button.

Also, you had the wrong variable typed in while sending the ajax request its `lname` but you have it as `lanme`

**Live Demo:** (Code tested and works)

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#myForm").on("submit", function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    //Values
    var fname = $("#fname").val();
    var lname = $("#lname").val();

    //Ajax
    $.ajax({
      url: "insertData.php",
      type: "POST",
      data: {
        fname: fname,
        lname: lname
      },
      success: function(data) {
        if (data == 1) {
          //tableData();
        } else {
          //alert("Can't save record");   
        }
      }
    });
  })
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<form id="myForm" autocomplete="off">
  <div class="form-group col-sm">
    <label for="fname">First Name</label>
    <input type="text" name="fname" id="fname" class="form-control">
  </div>
  <div class="form-group col-sm">
    <label for="lname">Last Name</label>
    <input type="text" name="lname" id="lname" class="form-control">
  </div>
  <div class="form-group col-sm">
    <button class="btn btn-primary" type="submit" id="submitBtn">Submit</button>
  </div>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

*Created a question from this post: [Why the form field ids are populated as JavaScript variables on submit button click?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63968462/why-the-form-field-ids-are-populated-as-javascript-variables-on-submit-button-cl)*

There is a bit more to the problem - why the stack overflow exception from jquery instead of some indication for the misspelled variable.

Consider this code:

```html
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function()
{
    $("#submitBtn").on("click", function(e)
    {
        console.log(911, a);
        e.preventDefault();
    })
});
</script>
</head>
<body>
<form>
    <input type="text" id="a" />
    <button type="submit" id="submitBtn">Submit</button>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

As you can see, the variable `a` is defined and references the HTML element with the id "a". Can anybody explain why?

This is what happened in the original code - the lname field in the data JSON was set to a reference of an HTML element, which is handled badly by jquery, meaning it lead to an infinite recursion.