# Why the form field ids are populated as JavaScript variables on submit button click?

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, onclick, submit

Consider this code:

```html
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function()
{
    $("#submitBtn").on("click", function(e)
    {
        console.log(911, a);
        e.preventDefault();
    })
});
</script>
</head>
<body>
<form>
    <input type="text" id="a" />
    <button type="submit" id="submitBtn">Submit</button>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

The `a` variable is never defined or initialized explicitly, and yet it has a value and references an HTML element. Why is that?

Based on the following issue: [When inserting data to database using JavaScript Error creates in console 'Maximum call stack size exceeded'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63968046/when-inserting-data-to-database-using-javascript-error-creates-in-console-maxim)

Comment: IDs are [global attribute](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes/id). You can for instance write in the console **window.submitBtn** and you get the submit element.... The window object contains  theDOM document loaded in that window

Comment: how did i not know this until now?! thank you :)